# What does [core] in .gitconfig do, and how to set it up?

Tags: git, git-config

I wish to know what does [core] do, and how to set it up in general. I found the .gitconfig file in my home directory to be this:

```
[core]
        autocrlf = input
        safecrlf = true

[user]
        name =  
        email =
```

In another home directory, it looks like this:

```
[user]
        name =
        email = 
[core]
        excludesfile = /Users/chenfl84/.gitignore_global
[difftool "sourcetree"]
        cmd = opendiff \"$LOCAL\" \"$REMOTE\"
        path =
[mergetool "sourcetree"]
        cmd = /Applications/SourceTree.app/Contents/Resources/opendiff-w.sh \"$LOCAL\" \"$REMOTE\" -ancestor \"$BASE\" -merge \"$MERGED\"
        trustExitCode = true
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See the [git-config(1)](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html) man page, or run `git help config` for general information on how Git configuration is arranged.

The `[core]` section refers to things that control the “core” of Git’s behavior: how files & updates are recognized, caching, compression, *etc*., *etc*.

The defaults are usually—just about always—what you want, but since many people *do* want to customize the `*crlf` options, they have been made explicit and put in a place convenient for changing.

Answer (score 7):

Each `[section]` begins a section that contains values. You could edit the file manually, or use `git config`, e.g.

```
git config --global core.name Pippi  # < value
#            section ^     ^ key
```

`git help config` has a list of options.